Error: could not decode result data
Hi i am using Hardhat local blockchain
My display() function in the App.jsx is not working it is giving the error :
App.jsx:106 Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "display", "signature": "display(address)" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.13.3)
I will share the display() function snippet in my App.jsx . Here it goes :
const getData = async () => {
try {
  let imgDataArr
  if (othAcc) {
    imgDataArr = await contract.display(othAcc)
  } else {
    imgDataArr = await contract.display(account)
  }
  console.log(imgDataArr)

  const isEmpty = Object.keys(imgDataArr).length == 0
  if (!isEmpty) {
    const str = imgDataArr.toString()
    const str_array = str.split(',')
    // console.log(str);
    // console.log(str_array);
    const images = str_array.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <a href={item} key={i} target="_blank">
          <img
            key={i}
            src={`https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${item.substring(6)}`}
            alt="new"
            className="image-list"
          ></img>
        </a>
      )
    })
    setImageList(images)
  } else {
    alert('No image found')
    return
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}

}
The error is actually occuring at the function call " contract.display() " where it is not able to decode the result " as per the error "
I will share the display() function snippet in my SmartContract . Here it goes :
function display(address user) external view returns (string[] memory) {
require(

  user == msg.sender || ownership[user][msg.sender],

  'You dont have access!'

);
return value[user];

}
**One more thing which i found was in my hardhat running server was **
WARNING: Calling an account which is not a contract
From:                0x15d34aaf54267db7d7c367839aaf71a00a2c6a65
To:                  0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
I HAVE TRIED THE FOLLOWING FIXES :

Recompiled and deployed my smart contract using npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
Switched between different acc's / Imported new accounts in metamask

Any suggestions / solution would be of great help !
Thank you

data='0x' usually means you're calling to non-existing contract, it can be caused by: wrong address, wrong network/provider.
There is something you need to check at first:

Did you run npx hardhat node?
Check your provider which your contract instance is connecting to. Confirm provider HTTP json rpc URL localhost:8545
Is there any log on hardhat node when you calling? if no, you're not connecting to it.
Check your contract address on jsx and contract address you deployed.


WARNING: Calling an account which is not a contract
From: 0x15d34aaf54267db7d7c367839aaf71a00a2c6a65
To: 0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266

The address 0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266 is default address on npx hardhat node which was generated by test mnemonic. You sent a transaction which is calling to an EOA address instead of contract address. So hardhat raised a warning.
